# Route to controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I created an form_tag form:

```
<%= form_tag(set_image_dokumente_path) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :shit,'', data: {autocomplete_source: search2_patients_path}, :class => "shit" %>   
<% end %>
```

I try to route to set_image action of dokumente controller, but i get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `set_image_dokumente_path' for #<#<Class:0x711ff60>:0x762d578>
```

By default my form_tag goes to dokumente controller index action!
My routes:

```
resources :images

get "dokumente/index"
post "dokumente/index"

match 'patients/list' => 'patients#list'

resources :patients do
 collection do
  get :search2
 end
end
```

How do i have to change it?

Comment: You don't have a `set_image` named route under a `dokumente` resource, nor a `set_image_dokumente` named route. What do you expect? Please read the documentation.

Comment: i read it, but in my case i couldnt implement it! I tried several things! Sorry but im rails beginner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `as:` parameter to you route in order to create a named path.

For example:

```
post "dokumente/index", as: 'set_image_dokumente'
```

or similar, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but I hope you get the idea :)

More info:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code

Comment: No my aim is not to use the index action, i want that it routes to the action set_image! Previous i simply had: <%= form_tag do %> and that used the action index as well! Thanks